# System Monitor doesn't see enp0s5

Tags: networking, 22.04, parallels

I'm running KDE/Plasma 5.24.7 under Ubuntu 22.04 in a Parallels VM. Parallel's recommended networking option ("Shared networking") is working just fine — I have complete access to the internet. The Info Center app sees my IP address and the ethernet network interface just fine: enp0s5. However, the System Monitor does not, nor does the Network Speed widget; both report that there is no network connection. (See [attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pWjF.png).) I am wondering if this has to do with the change away from the old networking interface to Netplan. I also have a Parallels VM running Kali Linux, which I believe uses the older networking protocol, as its network interface is eth0, and System Monitor and the Network Speed widget see it without any problem. I would, of course, like to be able to use the System Monitor and the speed widget under Ubuntu, so any suggestions here (short of going back to the old network protocol) would be appreciated.